# MySQL Item_field::fix_fields function context object

Tags: c++, mysql

source code file:https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/5.6/sql/item.cc#L5381

function:bool Item_field::fix_fields

guys,I am a c++ beginner.i am trying use GDB to debug mysql.

now,I have a question:

in this function Item_field::fix_fields(),i found a object called "context->first_name_resolution_table":

```
from_field= find_field_in_tables(thd, this,
                                     context->first_name_resolution_table,
                                     context->last_name_resolution_table,
                                     reference,
                                     thd->lex->use_only_table_context ?
                                       REPORT_ALL_ERRORS : 
                                       IGNORE_EXCEPT_NON_UNIQUE,
                                     !any_privileges, TRUE);
```

but I  checked the function context.I could not find it。Can someone tell me that Why the context appear here.

thank you very much！

Comment: i found context comes from the base class Item_ident

Comment: it comes from “this” object

Answer (score 1):

context comes from “this” object.